# Where do I have to put my commas?

Tags: orthography, commas

Are the commas in the right places in the following sentence?

> I want to combine my experiences in software development
>   and network administration with the skills I acquired at university in one job.

Comment: Hello Jo, you might be interestd in joining with our new proposal 'English Language Learners'. Please, try now! (Downvote is not mine)

Comment: and ELL can be found at http://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's grammatically *correct*; but

1. You don't *combine* past experience and skills in a job, you *apply them* in it or *bring them to bear* on it.
2. What you're selling is not your *experiences*, plural, but your *experience*, singular
3. The phrase *in one job* is a   l o n g  way from the verb. That's a bit much for a harried recruiter, who is probably reading two or three hundred of these a day.

I suggest something more like:

> I want a position which draws upon both my [*CHARACTERIZE: extensive, hands-on, whatever you can claim*] experience in software development and network administration and the [*again, CHARACTERIZE or ENUMERATE*] skills I acquired at university.

Remember: nobody really cares what you say you want; everybody knows it's just a conventional sentence you have to include. Use it to say what you want your prospective employer to hear, which is those pieces I label *CHARACTERIZE*.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct without any commas. The prepositional phrases (*with the...*, *at uni...* and *in one...*) do not need to be separated from the main clause and in fact, belong with it.